# Check if select is displaying options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<select>
<option selected>Test 1</option>
<option>Test 2</option>
<option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

How do I check if the `<option>`s of the `<select>` are displayed? For example, this is considered as the `<option>`s of the `<select>` are displayed:

[image: Options of the select menu are displayed]

And this is considered that the `<option>`s of the `<select>` are not displayed:

[image: Options of the select menu are not displayed]

---

I have tried this:

```js
$("#myselect").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#myselect option").length == 0) {
        console.log("not displayed");
    } else {
        console.log("displayed");
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
<option selected>Test 1</option>
<option>Test 2</option>
<option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

But the console logs "displayed" all the time.

---

So how can I achieve this?

---

**EDIT 1:**

The answers at [How to check if an select element is still “open” / active with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123746/how-to-check-if-an-select-element-is-still-open-active-with-jquery) does not work because when I click the `select` element to display the options then click it again, the options are not displayed even though the `select` is still focused.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Just in case I wasn't explicit enough, basically I want the console to log "displayed" or "not displayed" the user clicks on the `select` or the `option`s

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if an select element is still "open" / active with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123746/how-to-check-if-an-select-element-is-still-open-active-with-jquery)

Comment: They're displayed if the `<select>` element has focus, but they will still exist when it doesn't (unless you were adding/removing them using JS code...).

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz The answer there does not work because I can press Escape and the select will still be in focus even though it is not displaying options

Comment: agree w/ @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz - the 2nd answer on that link is promising

Comment: right, check the second one

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz The 2nd answer revolves around the same concept on focusing which is not going to work... Check my edit

Comment: then just using click?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz I can click anywhere else on the document to trigger the options to not be displayed as well. Same for pressing `Escape`. And I guess there are many many other ways to hide the options without clicking on the `select` or the `option`s themselves.

Comment: check my answer. Maybe adding the Escape key condition will be ok?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try listening on click, blur and key press event. I am just toggling a `open` variable to `true or false` on each of the event.

```js
   // if menu is open then true, if closed then false
   // we start with false
   var open = false;
   // just a function to print out message
   function isOpen(){
       if(open)
          return "menu is open";
       else
          return "menu is closed";
   }
   // on each click toggle the "open" variable
   $("#myselect").on("click", function() {
         open = !open;
         console.log(isOpen());
   });
   // on each blur toggle the "open" variable
   // fire only if menu is already in "open" state
   $("#myselect").on("blur", function() {
         if(open){
            open = !open;
            console.log(isOpen());
         }
   });
   // on ESC key toggle the "open" variable only if menu is in "open" state
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
         if(open){
            open = !open;
            console.log(isOpen());
         }
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
<option selected>Test 1</option>
<option>Test 2</option>
<option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try clicking the `select`. This shows all the options and logs "menu is open".

Click the `select` again. This hides all the options and the console logs "menu is close".

Then click anywhere else that is not the `select`. Console logs "menu is open".

Your answer just needs a quick fix, other than that it seems to be working well.

Comment: If you use click/blur that fix problem with checking whether select is open. But there is a keys, ESC, ENTER, SPACE. 

So on space pressed, you should set it as open, on esc closed, on enter closed as well (actually click will be fired so we don't need to handle this)

Comment: in Firefox Developer Edition 68.0b10, running the code snippet does not at all work as described. When the menu is closed and you click to open it, no event is fired. Nothing logged in console. It just alternates between "menu is open" and "menu is closed" each time the menu is closed.

Comment: This will fail in earlier versions of Chrome, because of `Enter` key. Check out my implementation with a perfect example

Answer (score 4):

You can use `change` event in case of `not displayed`, and `focus` event for `displayed`

```js
$("#myselect").on({
  "change": function() {
    $(this).blur();
  },
  'focus': function() {
    console.log("displayed");
  },
  "blur": function() {
    console.log("not displayed");
  },
  "keyup": function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27)
      console.log("displayed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option selected>Test 1</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this could cause some errors, if the select is focused at init... right? maybe it´s better this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11123910/3617531

Comment: And check the post's edit about why `focus` doesn't work very well

Comment: Still doesn't work when I press the `select` to show the options, then press it again to hide the options.

Answer (score 1):

After reading, I´ve realized that Option tags are not "usual" DOM elements. Then, is not so easy to control it (instead you are checking click, blur, and combining other methods as we started trying before).

Now I´ve managed you finally found the solution in a mix of the first idea we had, then, i´ll just explain the other possible solutions you have and all the things I´ve learned about selects:

> - If you DON´t add a size attribute to the select, you will not be able to detect keypress at the time it´s open.
> - If you add a size attribute bigger than 1 to the select, it will detect keypress, but will loose it´s format and a list will appear.
> - If you try to use offset, and similar, to check wether the select is open, is also not working, as the option objects do not have offset
>     functions... (they are not usuarl DOM objects)
> - Click/focus will also not be enough, as the focus remains in select after a "ESC" click.

Then, after all those things reviewed, I think it´s not possible to make it in a pure HTML way without doing a lot of click/blur controls like answered before.

Anyway, to clarify, there are lots of [jquery librarys](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) that will help you to simulate a select/option dropdown, and to control if it´s open.

I hope this answer will solve your Question. Check this functional fiddle I´ve prepared for you to show the jquery dropdown way:

```js
$('#jq-dropdown-1').on('show', function(event, dropdownData) {
  console.log("SHOWN");
}).on('hide', function(event, dropdownData) {
  console.log("HIDDEN");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/claviska/jquery-dropdown/master/jquery.dropdown.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/claviska/jquery-dropdown/master/jquery.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">dropdown</a>
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
  <ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="jq-dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<button id="clickme">click me</button>
```

Those are the docs I´ve read to understand it:

- [jQuery keypress/keyup/etc events not fired when select box is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648990/jquery-keypress-keyup-etc-events-not-fired-when-select-box-is-expanded)
- [How to detect escape key press with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369593/how-to-detect-escape-key-press-with-javascript)
- [jQuery Event Keypress: Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557321/jquery-event-keypress-enter-key)
- [Keypress event on chosen single select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106161/keypress-event-on-chosen-single-select)

Comment: When I click on the `select`, it logs `open`. I click the `select` again, and it closes, yet `open` is logged again. So this doesn't work too well...

Comment: I´m checking the ESC key event is only fired when the select is closed...  trying to correct...

Comment: What does this have to do with the `select` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Im suggesting you to use new jquery selectmenu which is providing selectmenu open event

```js
$("#myselect").selectmenu({
  open: function(event, ui) {
    alert("opened");
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option selected>Test 1</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Ref : http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-open

Comment: I am using a lot of plugins already and I do not wish to use another one... But anyway this a very straightforward answer

Answer (score 0):

The following may be worth trying out if you want an easier attempt.  Simply :focus on the element.

```js
  var $mselect = window.jQuery("select");
  $mselect.focus(function () {
    console.log('select values should be visible');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
cnt = document.getElementById('your_select').childElementCount;

if (cnt == 0) {
  ...
}
```

There are no option elements in `your_select` element.

Answer (score -3):

Solution:

`select` is an input, it has a focus state, so when it's focused the list(options) will be displayed, when it's not the list of options will disappear. So:

```
$("#myselect").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#mySelect").is(":focus")) {
        console.log("displayed");
    } else {
        console.log("not displayed");
    } 
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @chris97ong i don't think that there's a solution for what you're asking, especially in IE

Comment: you can have focus on select and still options can be hidden by getting to select by `tab` key

Answer (score -3):

What about simple check when jquery is 1.6+

```
  if ($(".selector").is(":focus")){
      // do stuff
  }
```

or

```
$(".selector").on('focus', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

It can do the trick.

Comment: This does nothing useful.

Comment: I am using this to discover if select from dropdown is visible on screen. IE: do not refresh something if select is on focus.