# Different events for <select> element when the drop down is opened or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a `<select>` element to respond differently to an *enter* key stroke depending on whether the dropdown is currently open or closed.

Is it possible to detect when a `<select>` element has the drop down list has opened or closed using JavaScript? Something like this, perhaps:

```
<select name="selExample" onChoicesOpen="console.log('opened');" onChoicesClosed="console.log('closed');">
```

Or is there a way to determine if the dropdown is open using Javascript.  Maybe something like:

```
$("#selExample").isDropDownOpen()
```

I'm OK if there is a solution that only works in Chrome (don't need IE support). I'm OK if the solution requires a library such as jQuery or something else.

Comment: Why don't `onfocus` and `onblur` accomplish your goal?

Comment: The field can have focus without the drop down list being opened, I am looking for when the drop down is opened and closed.

Comment: Maybe explain what you're actually trying to accomplish. See also http://xyproblem.info.

Comment: Off topic: Use event handlers in your script instead of in your HTML (`$('select.some-class').on('choicesOpen', function() {});` or the plain JS equivalent). It's just good practice.

Comment: @webwake I think this answers your question: [Check if select is displaying options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730270/11691977)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if select is displaying options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729501/check-if-select-is-displaying-options)

Comment: @isherwood i added some information about what i am trying to accomplish. I didn't use event handlers mostly to make the code more concise

Comment: onclick shuld do that